# Memoryless Property of Markov Chains

Tags: markov-chains

I'm trying to understand Markov Chains and have across the following in a book:

$ \sum\limits_{y=0,1,....m−1}p(x,y)P(T_A<T_B|X_0=x,X_1=y) $
which then becomes the following, under the Markov Property

$ \sum\limits_{y=0,1,....m−1}p(x,y)P(T_A<T_B|X_0=y) $

I understand that the Memoryless property of Markov Chains is being referred to, but I don't understand how it is being used to get X_0=y

I basically don't understand how to relate the above to the property,

$ P(X_{n+1}=x_{n+1}|X_0 = x_0, X_1 = x_1,......X_n = x_n) = P(X_{n+1}=x_{n+1}|X_n = x_n) $

Thank You

Comment: what are $T_A$ and $T_B$?

Comment: @LiuGang $T_A$ and $T_B$ are the times taken to reach Set A and Set B respectively.